# Linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am a newbie to C. I've just wrote a linked list program, compiled it, and received a segmentation error.  I have no clue where it went wrong. Can somebody help me?

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct snode{
  struct snode  *next;
  int val;
};

struct slist{
  struct snode *head;
  struct snode *tail;
  int len;
};

struct slist *mylist;

void slist_insert(int v){
  struct snode *newnode;
  newnode = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
  newnode -> val = v;
  newnode -> next = NULL;


  if(mylist->head  = NULL){
    mylist->head  = malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist->tail = (struct snode*)malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist->head = newnode;
    mylist->tail = newnode;

  }

  else{
    mylist -> tail -> next = (struct snode*)malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist -> tail -> next = newnode;
  };
   mylist -> len +=1;  
};


void main(){
    slist_insert(1);
    slist_insert(2);
    slist_insert(3);
    slist_insert(4);
    slist_insert(5);

    struct snode *temp;
    temp = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    temp = mylist-> head;
    while(temp -> next != NULL){
      printf("%d\n", temp -> val);
      temp  = temp -> next;
    };
  };
```

Comment: There's at least an argument that this belongs on Stack Overflow since you aren't asking for a review of working code but are asking for help with resolving a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One key problem is:

```
 if(mylist->head  = NULL){
```

First, you've not checked whether `mylist` itself is NULL, and on the first call to `slist_insert()`, it is NULL.  That alone leads to trouble.

Second, you've got an assignment in there instead of a comparison; you need a comparison.

When it comes down to it, you need to handle the empty list case and not `mylist->head == NULL`.  The code inside the `if (mylist->head = NULL)` is extremely problematic.  You allocate two node values, then you overwrite the pointers with `newnode`, leaking memory.  The code does not set `mylist->len` either.  You have a similar memory leak in the `else` clause.

```
if (mylist == NULL)
{
    mylist = malloc(sizeof(*mylist));  // or sizeof(struct slist)
    mylist->head = newnode;
    mylist->tail = newnode;
    mylist->len  = 1;
}
else
{
    mylist->tail->next = newnode;
    mylist->tail = newnode;
    mylist->len++;
}
```

You have a number of places where you leave spaces around the `->` operator; don't!  It binds very tightly and should never have spaces around it.  Ditto for the `.` operator.

Do not write `void main()`.  It isn't valid in standard C; <s>it isn't valid in Microsoft C</s> (see Stack Overflow and [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for more detailed information).  Further, since Microsoft C is based on C89, you must also include a `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.  In C99 and C11, that is optional (though that is IMNSHO a bug in the standard) and you are best off always using `return 0;` or equivalent at the end of `main()`.

In the `main()` function, you don't need the allocation.

```
struct snode *temp = mylist->head;
while (temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n", temp->val);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

You should not have an empty declaration after the `main()` program — the semicolon after the close brace is technically an empty declaration.  Omit the semicolon.  Ditto after `slist_insert()`.

You don't need the empty statement (semicolon) after the `while` loop in `main()`, either.  Nor do you need the empty statement after the `else` block in `slist_insert()`.  These don't do much harm, but they don't do any good either.

At some point, you need to add the code to release the list.

Your code is not very general.  You are tied to a single list.  You should be able to create an empty list, and then pass that list to `slist_insert()` so you could have multiple lists concurrently.  Global variables (like `mylist`) are bad when they can be avoided — and this one could be avoided.  However, this is a secondary issue; you have a lot of primary issues to resolve first.

An alternative design would use `struct slist mylist;` as the global variable, avoiding the need to dynamically allocate the list.  However, that doesn't work well for the generalized version, so I don't recommend implementing it (except as an exercise).

Personally, I'd create types for the structures:

```
typedef struct snode snode;
typedef struct slist slist;
```

and I'd use those in the code.  I haven't implemented that.

Your code does not check that `malloc()` returns a non-null pointer; neither does mine, but that is lazy.  However, you also don't have an easy way to indicate the problem with the current interface — other then a unilateral exit from the program.  I've used `assert()` statements to deal with this.  I've also tagged the lines 'reprehensible' because using `assert()` for checking memory allocation is a very bad idea — only marginally less bad than not checking at all.

Here is working code incorporating most of the points raised above (and probably a few other minor details).  I left the debugging code I added while sorting out the problems; you can see what I used and work out why.  Every print except the one in the `while` loop in `main()` is debugging code.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct snode
{
    struct snode *next;
    int val;
};

struct slist
{
    struct snode *head;
    struct snode *tail;
    int len;
};

struct slist *mylist;

extern void slist_insert(int v);
extern void slist_destroy(void);

void slist_insert(int v)
{
    struct snode *newnode = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    assert(newnode != NULL);  // Reprehensible
    newnode->val = v;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if (mylist == NULL)
    {
        mylist = malloc(sizeof(*mylist));
        assert(mylist != NULL); // Reprehensible
        mylist->head = newnode;
        mylist->tail = newnode;
        mylist->len  = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(mylist->head != 0);
        assert(mylist->tail != 0);
        assert(mylist->tail->next == 0);
        mylist->tail->next = newnode;
        mylist->len++;
        mylist->tail = newnode;
    }
}

void slist_destroy(void)
{
    struct snode *curr = mylist->head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Free: %d\n", curr->val);
        struct snode *next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
    printf("Free: mylist\n");
    free(mylist);
    mylist = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Before 1\n");
    assert(mylist == 0);
    slist_insert(1);
    assert(mylist != 0);
    printf("Before 2\n");
    slist_insert(2);
    printf("Before 3\n");
    slist_insert(3);
    printf("Before 4\n");
    slist_insert(4);
    printf("Before 5\n");
    slist_insert(5);

    printf("Before loop\n");

    struct snode *temp = mylist->head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    slist_destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 good points and revised code.  Although the OP was just concerned about the error, I'm sure this information was needed as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! I definitely helped out! Really appericiated